# How to read all zipfile in python

Tags: python, encryption, zip, pycryptodome, python-zipfile

I have a zipfile
for example, i changed some files in zip and i need to encrypt it and after that save

```
def encrypt(self, zipfile: ZipFile):
    import base64
    with open(self.__db_path, 'wb') as db_file:
        decrypted_data = zipfile.read()
    
    aes = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_OFB)

    encrypted_data = aes.encrypt(decrypted_data)

    with open(self.__db_path, 'wb') as db_file:
        db_file.write(encrypted_data)
```

But this code throwing the exception, cause code expected argument "name" to read some files into the zip
How i can read all zip file to encrypt it and save?

Comment: maybe save it to a new zip file?

Comment: can you show example?

Comment: You need to set the IV for OFB mode to something unique. The IV doesn't need to be secret. Usually we write it in front of the ciphertext and send it along. During decryption we read the first 16 bytes (for AES) and use that as the IV.

Comment: mode is doesn't matter cause i need to get a binary of my zip to rewrite it

Answer (score 0):

You should actually specify the name of your zipfile when using `.write` method.

The last line would be

`db_file.write(encrypted_data, zipfile)`

Comment: i mean that i can't get the decrypted data to encrypt it cause i can't get a binary code of my zipfile